# change file name before upload to server asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-core-mvc

> Hi, I want to change file name before upload to server and store path
>   in database . Here is my code. But it uploads file with same name. I
>   want to change name (with guid). How can I do that?

```
 [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SaveAsync(NewPostViewModel model, IFormFile postImage)
        {

            var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(new NewsDbContext(_contextOptions));

           // My domain class which is contains CoverPhotoPath property
            var post = new Post();

            if (postImage != null && postImage.Length > 0)
            {
                string filename = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(postImage.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');

                filename = this.EnsureCorrectFilename(filename);
                using (FileStream output = System.IO.File.Create(this.GetPathAndFilename(filename)))
                    await postImage.CopyToAsync(output);
             // this is my photo path in database 
                post.CoverPhotoPath = filename;
            }


            unitOfWork.Posts.Add(post);
            unitOfWork.Compelete();

            return RedirectToAction("List", "News");
        }
```

> My methods

```
private string EnsureCorrectFilename(string filename)
        {
            if (filename.Contains("\\"))
                filename = filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);

            return filename;
        }


 private string GetPathAndFilename(string filename)
    {
        return _environment.WebRootPath + "\\files\\" + filename;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is my upload method using FileStream, hope it helps

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFileImage(ICollection<IFormFile> files)
    {
        string file_name = "the file name";
        var uploads = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "uploads/Image");
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, file_name ), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its quite late but maybe this can help.
Just Copy your old file to a new one and Delete the older one after uploading your file. Like:

```
 var oldFilePath = folderPath + fileName; //filename: Uploading file
 using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(oldFilePath))
                {
                    await item.CopyToAsync(fileStream);

                }
 var newFileName = someCustomString + fileName;
 var newFilePath = folderPath + newFileName;

 System.IO.File.Copy(oldFilePath, newFilePath, true);
 System.IO.File.Delete(oldFilePath);
```

Comment: Where do you change the file name exactly?

Comment: @Progressive I create a new file name with customizing my older file name (which was uploaded). Then I create a path to the same folder with the new FileName. 

  `var newFileName = someCustomString + fileName;
  var newFilePath = folderpath + newFileName`

I'll edit my Answer aswell